# asihttprequest Image download

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Hello good morning everyone. I am using asihttprequest for a series of images download - 4 images from server.However i noticed an issues and cannot find a solution. Suppose i am downloading 4 images via URL and in case any one or 2 of the images is not available it cancels the whole queue.

Here is my code :

```
    [networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressIndicator];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetchComplete:)];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(imageFetchFailed:)];

    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://imagees/image1.jpg"]];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"]];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:imageProgressIndicator1];
    [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sdvdsvsadvsadv"]] autorelease];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.png"]];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:imageProgressIndicator2];
    [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request2" forKey:@"name"]];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

- (void)imageFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[request downloadDestinationPath]];
    if (img) {
        if ([imageView1 image]) {
            if ([imageView2 image]) {
                [imageView3 setImage:img];
            } else {
                [imageView2 setImage:img];
            }
        } else {
            [imageView1 setImage:img];
        }
    }
}

- (void)imageFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if (!failed) {
        if ([[request error] domain] != NetworkRequestErrorDomain || [[request error] code] != ASIRequestCancelledErrorType) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download failed" message:@"Failed to download images" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [alertView show];
        }
        failed = YES;
    }
}
```

The problem is that suppose fetching second image failed, it displays the error message and stops the whole operation, although image 1 is a valid image file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use):

> When a request in an ASINetworkQueue fails, the queue will by default
>   cancel all other requests. You can disable this behaviour with [queue
>   setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO].